# How can I add key : value to an object only if key does not already exist? If key exists already then edit value

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable, associative-array

I'm taking a list from a plain text file like this:

```
2: B D E
5: B C
```

and using javascript (with no plug-ins) to rearrange the list like this

```
B: 2 5
D: 2
E: 5


        // rest of code file input , etc. not necessary to list here, imho

        var contents = e.target.result; // read contents of file

        var oldParts = contents.split(/\n/); // put each line of contents into array

        for (i = 0; i < oldParts.length; i++) {

            var allChar = oldParts[i].split( ' ' ); // each character from the line

            var truck = {};

            var tractor = "";

            var trailer = "";

            for (j = 0; j < allChar.length; j++) { 

                allChar[j] = allChar[j].replace(":", ""); // remove the ":" delimiter

                allChar[j].trim();

                trailer = allChar[0]; // get just the numbers

                if ( isNaN ( allChar[j] ) ) { // is not a number

                    tractor = allChar[j];


                    if ( truck.hasOwnProperty(tractor) ) {

                        console.log ( "already in" );

                    } else { 

                        console.log ( " needs to be added" ) ;

                        truck [ tractor ] = trailer;

                    }

                }

            }


            for ( tractor in truck ) {

                document.write ( tractor + " : " + truck[tractor] + "<br />" );

            } 

        }
```

the above code will write:

```
B: 2
D: 2
E: 2
B: 5
C: 5
```

which is close but I'm trying to check the property of truck if it is equal to tractor just append the trailer

everything I try the truck property is undefined

I've tried

```
truck [ tractor ] = trailer;

if (tractor in truck) { // never is
```

how can I get the value of truck [ tractor ] to see what I need to do next?

Comment: The thing that you say you've tried, is in fact what you need to do. Why don't you post the code where you tried that -- a minimal example that allows us to reproduce your problem -- and we can help you find where it's going wrong?

Comment: Ok, thank you @ruakh. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watertower/2kdt2nz0/) of the code example. 

Thing is, even though I am clearly loading tractor property with trailer value into the truck object, if ( tractor in truck ) cannot find it

Comment: To clarify: by "minimal example", I mean that you should reduce your code to the absolute minimal program that behaves differently from what you expect. Your minimal program would not require reading from a file, so reproducing the problem would not require us to create a text file. (You need to put forth some effort here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.)

Comment: how does "E", in your example above, get a "5" when it is clear sitting on the "2:" line. Slightly confused here. When I say 'how', I really mean why?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you mean your output should be as follows:

given this:

```
2: B D E
5: B C
```

you want:

```
B: 2 5
D: 2
E: 2
C: 5
```

Here is a shorter, simplified version:

```
var data = "2: B D E\n5: B C";
var hashTable = {}, finalString = "";

var dataArray = data.split("\n");
dataArray.forEach(function(i){
  var tempArr = i.split(':');
  tempArr[1].split(' ').forEach(function(j){
    if([undefined, ''].indexOf(j) != -1) return;

    (j in hashTable ) ? hashTable[j].push(tempArr[0].trim()) : hashTable[j] = [tempArr[0]];
  })
});
(function(){
   for(var s in hashTable){
     finalString += s + ": " + hashTable[s].join(' ') + "\n";
   }
}())
console.log(finalString);
//B: 2 5
//D: 2
//E: 2
//C: 5
```